# Code runs on IDE but not on Linux machine - C

Tags: c, linux, ide

The code runs in Code::Blocks environment as expected. However on a Linux machine it is not working as expected.

Problem statement : On Linux, it does not read the input file.

Purpose: Read from the text file provided in the input and output two text files.

output_n.txt:

```
---List of Positive Cases---
--Flea X:+Positive+
--Anthony Kiedis:+Positive+
--Jack Irons:+Positive+
--Cliff Martinez:+Positive+
```

output_p.txt:

```
---List of Negative cases:---
--Chad Smith:-Neg-
--John Frusciante:-Neg-
--Arik Marshall:-Neg-
```

This is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 7

int c = 0;
char band_diagnose[SIZE];

int read_doctor_list(char filename[], char type[], char band_names[][20], char band_diagnose[])
{
    char line[100];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, type);
    if (!filename)
    {
        printf("Fail to open the file");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while (fgets(line, 100, fp))
        {
            if (c % 2 == 0)
            {
                strcpy(band_names[i], line);
                strtok(band_names[i], "\n");
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!strcmp(line, "Positive\n"))
                {
                    band_diagnose[j] = 'P';
                }
                else if (!strcmpi(line, "Negative\n"))
                {
                    band_diagnose[j] = 'N';
                }

                j++;
            }

            c++;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

void band_practice_list(char filename[], char status[], char band_names[][20], char band_diagnose[])
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!filename)
    {
        printf("Fail to open the file!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (!strcmp(status, "Positive"))
        {
            char pos[] = "+Positive+";
            fprintf(fp, "---List of Positive Cases---\n");
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if (band_diagnose[i] == 'P')
                {
                    fprintf(fp, "--%s:%s\n", band_names[i], pos);
                }
            }

            fclose(fp);
        }

        if (!strcmp(status, "Negative"))
        {
            rewind(fp);
            char neg[] = "-Neg-";
            fprintf(fp, "---List of Negative cases:---\n");

            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if (band_diagnose[i] == 'N')
                {
                    fprintf(fp, "--%s:%s\n", band_names[i], neg);
                }
            }

            fclose(fp);
        }

        printf("Creating list...\n");
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (band_diagnose[i] == 'P')
            {
                printf("%s:%c...Can't go to practice!:(\n\n", band_names[i], band_diagnose[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s:%c...Good to go to practice!:)\n\n", band_names[i], band_diagnose[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char band_names[SIZE][20];
    char band_diagnose[SIZE];

    int n = read_doctor_list("doctorlist.txt", "r", band_names, band_diagnose);

    if (n)
    {
        band_practice_list("output_p.txt", "Positive", band_names, band_diagnose);
        band_practice_list("output_n.txt", "Negative", band_names, band_diagnose);
    }
}
```

This is the input file, doctorlist.txt:

```
Flea X
Positive
Anthony Kiedis
Positive
Chad Smith
Negative
John Frusciante
Negative
Jack Irons
Positive
Cliff Martinez
Positive
Arik Marshall
Negative
```

Screenshot of my program run in Code::Blocks:
[image: Screenshot of my program run in Code::Blocks]

In Linux enviromment:
[image: In Linux enviromment]

Comment: `doctorlist.txt` has CRLF line breaks. On Windows they will be converted to to `\n`, but on Linux they're kept as `\r\n` so your comparisons don't work.

Comment: If you created the file on Windows then you may have Windows line endings that can cause issues on other operating systems. Try using Notepad++ to convert to Unix line endings or use the dos2unix program on the Linux machine to fix the file.

Comment: Use `dos2unix doctorlist.txt` to fix it.

Comment: You can also use `strtok(line, "\n\r");` to trim both characters from the end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Even though your question is quite well for a first question, please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". -- Please do not show textual input or output as screenshots, copy the text as such.

Answer (score 0):

> Code runs on IDE but not on Linux machine

On Linux, you could edit your C code with [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](https://vim.org/) or [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) etc..., then compile your code with the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (perhaps in a terminal) to get all warnings and debug info.

Read of course [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). See also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and man pages like [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) etc....

You probably want to use [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) when `fopen` fails.

Improve your C code to get no warnings at all from `gcc`

Then, use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. You could run your program step by step, ask values of variables, etc... from the debugger.

Consider also using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Be aware that in 2021 [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). Maybe you want to accept some input like `Gabrielles d'Estrées` in your `doctorlist.txt` file?